# $router.push doesn't respect route meta fields

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

When using `$router.push` like so:

```
this.$router.push({name: 'Home'})
```

... it seems my route meta fields aren't being recognised. Here's my route meta fields and how I'm calling them:

**Route meta fields**

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
    // this route requires auth, check if logged in
    // if not, redirect to login page.
    if (!auth.user.authenticated) {
      next({
        path: '/login'
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.preventAdmin)) {
    // this route shouldn't be available for admin, check role
    // if so, redirect to admin area.
    if (auth.user.role === '1') {
      next({
        path: '/admin/users'
      })
    } else {
      next()
    }
  } else {
    next() // make sure to always call next()!
  }
})
```

**Routes**

```
routes: [
  {
   path: '/',
   name: 'Home',
   component: Home,
   meta: { requiresAuth: true, preventAdmin: true }
  },
]
```

If I refresh when I am on the particular route they work as intended.

Do I have to do something to ensure my route meta fields work when using `$router.push`?

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your router-view as such:

```
<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>
```

to reach the same result as page refreshing on page routing (for the contents of your router-view at least). I would expect that to do the trick, but let me know if it doesn't.

Comment: I'm using `this.$router.push({name: 'Home'})` as part of a login method so `<router-view :key="$route.path"></router-view>` isn't available.

Comment: That doesn't mean that it's not available, right? The key parameter of the router-view is simply triggered whenever and however you navigate to a different page, including `this.$router.push({ })`